# Append filename from href without path

Tags: jquery, split, append

**Thanks for all the replies. There are multiple correct answers, I'm running with Arun's answer because it appears the cleanest solution. Cheers all.**

The following works as intended...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {

    jQuery(".jg-entry").each(function() {

    jQuery(this).append(jQuery('<h6/>', {text: jQuery(this).parent().find('a').prop('href')}));

    });
});
```

...it appends each 'a' link between h6 tags in a specified div. However, I'd like to only include the filename without its path.

Currently it outputs (for example)

```
<h6>http://localhost/client/content/photos/image.jpg</h6>
```

but I'd like it to simply output the filename like so...

```
<h6>image.jpg</h6>
```

html looks like this:

```
<div class="jg-entry">
<a href="http://localhost/client/content/photos/photo1.jpg"><img src="http://localhost/client/content/photos/photo1-large.jpg"></a><h6>http://localhost/client/content/photos/photo1.jpg</h6>
</div>
```

I've done a ton of searching and playing around. I hit a few threads which were similar, but I haven't managed (I'm not good enough) to figure it out.

Thanks!

B.

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: Added html as requested

Comment: Have added my Answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) like below

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".jg-entry").each(function () {
        $(this).append($('<h6/>', {
            text: $(this).find('a').attr('href').split('/').pop()
        }));
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L7mfa4bm/)

Also no need to call .parent() as the `anchor` is a child of the `.jg-entry` entry.

Comment: This appears to be the cleanest approach and I appreciate you considering the unnecessary .parent() - You get the thumbs up on this one Arun. Thanks to everyone else who answered.

Answer (score 0):

Using split.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
    jQuery(".jg-entry").each(function() {
        var paths = jQuery(this).parent().find('a').prop('href').split("/"),
            filename = paths[paths.length-1];       
        jQuery(this).append(jQuery('<h6/>', {text:filename}));
    });
});
```

Comment: First in best dressed.. this works exactly as intended, thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Try below:-

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {

   jQuery(".jg-entry").each(function() {

   var  yourstring = jQuery(this).parent().find('a').prop('href');
   var fileNameIndex = yourstring.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
   var filename = yourstring.substr(fileNameIndex);

jQuery(this).append(jQuery('<h6/>', {text:filename  }));

}); });
```

Comment: Not exactly sure why, but I couldn't get this to work. Thanks anyway, I've been provided a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {

    jQuery(".jg-entry").each(function() {

    var link = jQuery(this).parent().find('a').prop('href');
    jQuery(this).append(jQuery('<h6/>', {text: link.substring(data.lastIndexOf('/')+1,data.length)}));

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.split('/').pop()`:

`.split('/')` lets you create an array out of your string and `.pop()` will return you the last item resides in the created array which is the image name `"photo1.jpg"`.

```js
jQuery(".jg-entry").each(function() {
  jQuery(this).append(jQuery('<h6/>', {
    text: jQuery(this).parent().find('a').prop('href').split('/').pop()
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jg-entry">
  <a href="http://localhost/client/content/photos/photo1.jpg">
    <img src="http://localhost/client/content/photos/photo1-large.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/xsnj7z3q/)

```
$(function ($) {
    $(".jg-entry").each(function () {
        $(this).append($('<h6/>', {
            text: $(this).find('a').prop('href').split('/').pop()
        }));
    });
});
```